# Can't find my saved .jpg's

Tags: search

I just installed U 16.04 (fresh).  I saved all my .jpg's from a search on U 12.04 to a external HD.  I can not find them by looking thru folders.  When I search the external HD, all 5349 of them show up.  This is what remained, after I removed all the duplicates.  How do I get the .jpg's to show what folder they are in, up so that I can spend the rest of my life sorting them?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Your files are on an external HDD and they show up, but you can't find them? Where exactly do you expect to find them, other than on the external HDD?

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

```
locate *.jpg
```

Your `jpg` files should all be displayed with their paths.

Comment: When I look in all the folders I saved for the new install of U 16.04, there are no .jpg's to see.  When I do a search (with the magnifying glass icon), on the external drive, all the .jpg's I saved show up.  All 5349 of them, = 4.5GB.I just looked again. There are NO folders with 5,349 .jpgs or 4.5GB.  Is this more clear Tom?  I don't know how else to explane it.

Comment: I tried the terminal as you explained and they don't show up.  Thanks

Comment: I am withdrawing my question, since there is no answer.  It seems Tommy doesn't know